# Aligning buttons with CSS

Tags: html, css

So basically I've been trying to center align two buttons on my website, and literally none of the common methods worked. It doesn't move no matter what, and nothing else is overriding it. I may be missing something but this is such a headache.

My CSS button code:

```css
.btn {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-color: #346cfc !important
}
.btn-secondary {
    background-color: #346cfc !important;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
</nav>
<div class="heading">
<h1 class="display-5 title"></i>Ricky</h1>
<p class="subtitle">Ricky is a multi purpose bot with features like Music, Economy, Utility, and more!<br />Check out the <a href="https://docs.partywumpus.com">docs</a> or get started below.</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center"href="https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=778817321640394762&scope=bot&permissions=2147483647" target="_blank" role="button">Invite</a>
<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg text-center"href="https://discord.gg/XXBpY2v6AU" target="_blank" role="button">Support Server</a>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

I did find something that worked, making the position relative worked. But it looks bad on mobile depending on what I set the top and left % as

```css
.btn-primary {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #7289DA !important
}
```

Any better way to do this than just making it look bad on PC or mobile?

Comment: What’s your specific “*[mcve]*” html? Is there any css cascading from ancestors that overrides your css? Is it “just two buttons”, are there any sibling elements or a parent element?

Comment: Edited for better understanding

Comment: "align" how? Horizontally, vertically, to each other, to something else, center them?

Comment: Edited again for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your button to a div

```js
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center"href="https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=778817321640394762&scope=bot&permissions=2147483647" target="_blank" role="button">Invite</a>
  <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg text-center"href="https://discord.gg/XXBpY2v6AU" target="_blank" role="button">Support Server</a>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: "flex";
  align-items: "center";
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/